# Problems with calculating 95% confidence interval using scipy.stats library

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, statistics

I need to calculate p-value, ods ratio and 95% confidence interval for matrix 2x2 usin python. I found `scipy.stats` library

```
import scipy.stats as stats

v = [[8, 2], [1, 5]]
oddsratio, pvalue = stats.fisher_exact(v)

print(pvalue, oddsratio, sep="\n")  # 0.03496503496503495 and 20.0 (15.47 on R)
```

But I am having problems with calculating 95% confidence interval. I [found](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.interval.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.interval) `scipy.stats.rv_continuous.interval` method

```
v_continuous.interval(self, alpha, *args, **kwds)[source]
    Confidence interval with equal areas around the median.

Parameters
    alphaarray_like of float
    Probability that an rv will be drawn from the returned range. Each value should be in the range [0, 1].

    arg1, arg2, …array_like
    The shape parameter(s) for the distribution (see docstring of the instance object for more information).

    locarray_like, optional
    location parameter, Default is 0.

    scalearray_like, optional
    scale parameter, Default is 1.

Returns
    a, bndarray of float
    end-points of range that contain 100 * alpha % of the rv’s possible values.
```

I try next

```
a, b = stats.rv_continuous.interval(v, 0.95)
print(a, b, sep="\n")  # ~ 1.00884938039662 and 1049.79144613175 (calculated in R)
```

but got error

```
a = self.ppf(q1, *args, **kwds)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ppf'
```

How can I get the desired result?

Comment: I would not use `scipy.stats`'s `fisher_exact` test, which appears to be [incorrect](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/4130). You can try [this library](https://hail.is/docs/0.2/functions/stats.html#hail.expr.functions.fisher_exact_test) but it is not a light install (requires to run a JVM).

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't indicate what quantity the confidence interval is for. Assuming you're looking for a confidence interval of the odds ratio, you can use [`scipy.stats.contingency.odds_ratio`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.11.3/reference/generated/scipy.stats.contingency.odds_ratio.html) (new in SciPy 1.10.0).

```py
from scipy import stats
v = [[8, 2], [1, 5]]
res = stats.contingency.odds_ratio(v)
res.confidence_interval()
# ConfidenceInterval(low=1.0088492079476723, high=1059.6394950862782)
```